# Filling an array where one portion is linearly increasing and the rest is truncated

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm trying to fill an array of size 1 x 200 with values. I want the array to be filled with values ranging from 0 to 216 in steps of 6 and then keep the value constant (216) for the remaining part of the array.

How can I do that?

Comment: first calculate `floor` of 216/6, generate a vector of `ones(whatever floor gave you)*6` , now use `cumsum` to calculate the increment you want. Fill the rest of the values with 216.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to initially create an array from 0 to 216 in steps of 6, then concatenate the array of 216s until you reach 200 values.

Something like:

```
out = 0:6:216;
N = 200;
out(end+1:end+N-numel(out)) = 216;
```

Another way is to create 200 values of 216, then fill replace the values of the array from 1 up to `216/6 = 36` and add 1 since we're including 0; fill this in with the desired array:

```
N = 200; stop = (N/6) + 1;
out = 216*ones(1,N);
out(1:stop) = 0:6:216;
```

Finally, another way is to create an array from 0 up to 200, truncate all values that are greater than 36 to be 36, then multiply the result by 6:

```
N = 200;
out = 0:N;
out(out > 36) = 36;
out = 6*out;
```

... and as for completeness, you can do this with `min`<sup>1</sup>:

```
out = min(0:199,36)*6;
```

The two argument `min` call outputs the minimum of the first and second input for each element between two arrays of compatible sizes.  Should any of the inputs be constants, then this constant is compared with against all elements in the array.  The explanation for this code is to generate an array from 0 to 199, then any values that are less than 36 we keep, but any values greater stay at 36. We then multiply the result by 6 to obtain the result.

<sup>1: Credit for this answer goes to user [Stewie Griffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2338750/stewie-griffin) before he deleted his answer.  I decided to put this in for completeness.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = min(0:6:(6*199),216);
```

should work
or:

```
arr = min((0:199)*6,216);
```